# Start and Stop timer using OOP in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to create a start and stop timer using Object Oriented Javascript for the first time in `JavaScript`. I have no issues with starting the timer. The issue is topping it as it would not stop when i start it even when i use the `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout`. Please what is the issue with my code and lhow do i fix it?

```
function StopWatch() {
    let timer = 0;
    let starter = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            ++timer;
        }, 1000);
        // if(this.start) {
        //     throw new Error(`Timer already started`);
        // }
        console.log(timer);
    };
    let stopper = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(starter);
        console.log(timer)
    };
    this.start = starter;
    this.stop = stopper;
}
const sw = new StopWatch();
console.log(sw);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `starter` is a function, not a timer ID so you cannot use it in `clearTimeout`

Comment: You don't use the value returned from `setInterval`. You also then try to clear it using `clearTimeout`, while it should have been `clearInterval`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: @Phil I dont understand what you mean

Comment: `setInterval` (and `setTimeout`) [return an `intervalID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value) which you can use to stop them later. You are trying to use `starter` in `clearTimeout` which is a function and not an `intervalID`

Comment: @Phil i later understood what you were saying and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function returns a reference, which you pass to `clearInterval`:

```
const interval;
//... 
interval = setInterval(...);
//... 
clearInterval(interval);
```